# Tribonacci sequence in Haskell [Monads?]

Tags: haskell

```
trib :: Int -> Int  
trib 1 = 1  
trib 2 = 1  
trib 3 = 2   
trib n | n > 3 = trib (n-3) + trib (n-2) + trib (n-1)
```

This code generates a Tribonacci sequence but this is super slow

How to do something similar using a State Monad that will take less time?

After using a fibonacci code from textbook I was able to get a basic skeleton but not sure about stateTrib operations

```
stateTrib :: Integer -> State (Integer,Integer,Integer) ()
 stateTrib = ??? 
 runStateTrib :: Integer -> Integer
 runStateTrib n = let ((),(a,b,c)) = (runState (stateTrib n) (1,0,0)) in a
```

Comment: `State` is entirely optional, you can solve it efficiently with plain recursion.

Comment: Also, the ` | n > 3` guard is unnecessary

Comment: `State a ()` is isomorphic to `a -> a`, and in most cases the latter type is both simpler and more idiomatic to program with.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `State` to solve it efficiently, just use plain recursion to update the accumulator:

```hs
trib (a, _, _) 1 = a
trib (_, b, _) 2 = b
trib (_, _, c) 3 = c
trib (a, b, c) n = trib (b, c, a + b + c) (n - 1)
```

But if you really desire to involve `State`, then the change would be mainly in the way the accumulator is accessed:

```hs
stateTrib 1 = gets $ \(a, _, _) -> a
stateTrib 2 = gets $ \(_, b, _) -> b
stateTrib 3 = gets $ \(_, _, c) -> c
stateTrib n = do
  (a, b, c) <- get
  put (b, c, a + b + c)
  stateTrib (n - 1)
```

Note that the `State` version is likely to be slower than plain recursion (not sure how the optimizer would handle it).